# Set selected text in SelectionArea

Tags: flutter, dart, text, textselection

I understand how to read the selected text in a `SelectionArea`, but I would also like to *make* selections as well. Given access to a `SelectionArea`, how do I programmatically set what it is selecting?

Thanks!

Comment: Same questions here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know SelectionArea does not have an easy way to do that or at least I have not seen documentation about it, , where I have seen what can be done in the TextFields, here I leave you an example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController()
    ..text = 'Hello World example';
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                focusNode: focusNode,
                controller: controller,
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //focus
                    focusNode.requestFocus();

                    //select all
                    controller.selection = TextSelection(
                        baseOffset: 0,
                        extentOffset: controller.text.length,
                        isDirectional: true);
                  },
                  child: const Text('Select All'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```